# c# win forms make controls resizable

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a panel with two controls inside. I wish they were sticked to border of panel (panel has some width and height that cant be changed) but have possibility to resize the amount of space they (controls) get from panel in vertical direction.

```
panel.Controls.Add(listview1);
panel.Controls.Add(listview2);
```

Two listviews are placed one after another (vertically). I wish to have possibility to "change height" of them (by choosing border between them to resize).

I hope you understood what I mean. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Essentially you want to be able to change the area each listview takes up inside its parent container but have them share a border so that as one grows the other shrinks to occupy the remaining space? (just for clarity for other users)

Comment: You can look at (for example) at the TableLayoutPanel control in WinForms. You can use it to create some kind of grid. Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx

Comment: do you want to let users manually change size of controls, by dragging the edges?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using the [SplitContainer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx) from the Containers section of your designer toolbox.

Here's an [MSDN training video on using a SplitContainer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/Video/bb798031)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of [Table Layout Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to achieve that

Answer (score 2):

Set the doc property of the upper one to top.
Add a Splitter bar with orientation to vertical in the same container (panel). Set the lower one's Dock property to fill. 
One way of doing it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Paul that the [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx) is what you are looking for. I would add that you need to set the Dock and Anchor properties of the controls you put inside the split container. If you set a child control's `Dock` property to `Fill`, it will expand to fill up the entire container, regardless of how the panel is sized. The `Anchor` property is used if there are multiple controls in the panel. In that case, you set the child control's `Anchor` property to tell the child control which sides "stick" to the container's side. See [this page](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908) for a more comprehensive look at those two properties.

Also, you will want to set the `Dock` or `Anchor` properties on the `SplitContainer` control itself. That will make it resize when the form resizes. Then setting the `Anchor`/`Dock` properties on the child controls inside the `SplitContainer` will cause the child controls to resize as the container resizes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Anchor on the ListViews?

```
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        this.listView2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.listView2);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(413, 280);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // listView1
        // 
        this.listView1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 0);
        this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
        this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(410, 97);
        this.listView1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        // 
        // listView2
        // 
        this.listView2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.listView2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 183);
        this.listView2.Name = "listView2";
        this.listView2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(410, 97);
        this.listView2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.listView2.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(437, 304);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```